# ¿Por qué el ic_launcher de mi aplicación queda con fondo?

Tags: android-studio

el problema que tengo es que hice una imagen en Figma, un editor online, la imagen está sin fondo, pero al hacerla mi logo de app, se queda con fondo, no sé como hacer para que quede el logo sin el fondo de pantalla molesto y se vea solo mi logo.

Agradezco su ayuda !

[image: Así estoy haciendo mi Image Asset]
[image: Así es como queda]
[image: Y esta es mi imagen]

Comment: Sebas, cual es el sistema operativo de ese teléfono?

Comment: Android 6.0, no entiendo por qué pasa eso, no es solo con este teléfono

Answer (score 2):

Actualmente los nuevos iconos para Android deben crearse mediante 2 capas:
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

**Debes definir en el `Asset Studio` como "Foreground Layer" únicamente el icono y como "Background Layer" el fondo, que en este caso debería ser una imagen transparente.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al crear los iconos se obtendría un icono con fondo transparente para tu aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy agradecido, añadí la capa con canal alpha 0 de fondo y funcionó. Le puse 110px * 110px y la capa foreground tenía unos 300px * 300px y me lo aceptó.

Comment: Así es, puedes definir diferentes tamaños para cada capa, a cada una también puedes definir su Alpha, saludos.